# updating a table in informatica by giving precedence to a column

Tags: updates, informatica

I am updating a table with an ID based on some condition (
ex:id is null ) through target update overide concept.

My requirement is, there is an table_num coulmn  in the same table which has 3 values say 1,2,3.
Basically in dw terms I have to update the dimensions first and then the facts.Here 1 is a dimension where as 2 and 3 are facts.

So if i have 3 records with table_num 1,2,3 which has id as null.I should only update record with table_num=1.

Second scenario: if id is not null for table_num=1 and 2 and 3 are having nulls.Then i have to update 2 and 3.

Third SCenario: if 2 or 3 then update 2 or 3.

So basically table_num=1 should get the first precedence.

I know how to handle it in a pl/sql procedure and call a stored procedure tranformation.But i want to handle it in informatica.Could you please help me

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Lookupon your target table in your process:
Join condition: whatever column(s) you use to update your target
Output: table_num

For this to work you must configure the Lookup policy on multiple match (in the Properties tab of the Lookup) to **Use First Value** and add a Lookup Source Filter: **ID IS NULL**.

Then you can use the table_num from the Lookup as an additional condition to update your target. If the table_num = 1 has already been updated (i.e. ID IS NOT NULL), but the table_num = 2 has not, the table_num = 2 will be update.

I hope I got this right, let us know.